# Battery Monitoring Software

Tags: windows, battery

I've just got a Surface Book, and as I've read many different results as to the battery life of these, I'd like to monitor this.

So I'm looking for a program that runs on Windows 10, and does the following:

- Monitors battery life
- Gives an average battery life
- Detailed graph of battery percentage/rundown that covers weeks or months (instead of only since last charge)
- Monitors charging rate
- Give an average charge time
- Is able to work with two batteries of different capacities (as the Book has)

I prefer free software (who doesn't?) but would be interested in paid as well.

Full Windows programs *and* UWP apps welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the information that you require can be achieved with simple `powercfg /batteryreport` command in `command prompt` in windows.

It generates a nice html detail report of (in current folder) :

- Current FULL CHARGE CAPACITY
- Recent usage Battery
- Usage Graph with detailed tabled info as well
- Usage history Battery Capacity History
- Complete Tabled Battery Life estimate

I suggest you give it a try.

Comment: Aah what a lovely answer!! would have voted 10 times if allowed. This is useful

Answer (score 1):

The built-in Windows Task Manager can display such information, and can even display the battery usage of each application. If that is not enough, you can try BatteryMon too.

Comment: A URL for "BatteryMon" would have bee helpful