# App to check the current battery health?

Tags: gratis, battery, macos

I'm looking for macOS app to check for the current battery health, such as age, cycle count and capacity.

Preferably free app or with the trial version available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [coconut Battery](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/)

> It shows you live information about the battery in your Mac and iOS device (iPhone, iPad, iPod touch).

It can show the current battery charge and the maximum capacity (mAh), design capacity, model, manufacture date, cycle count, battery temperature, etc.

For Windows, check: [Battery Monitoring Software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/38015/3474).

Comment: It is encouraged to accept your own answer, because that will help others in future.